# One font not rendering in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts

I'm using @font face with Trade Gothic and Trade Gothic Bold for my client's website.

Both fonts render properly in browsers, except for IE.  In IE, the Trade Gothic is OK, but the Trade Gothic Bold doesn't display and resorts to arial.

Here's a link.  Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

http://www.shannon-brown.com/clients/Yeah/Yeah!-Invite.html

thanks,
Shannon

Comment: looks identical to me in IE9 and Firefox. Is it necessary to use the <b></b> tags if you are already using Trade Gothic Bold?

Answer (score 0):

typically the font will work if it is installed on the computer in question. an example is how Helvetica doesn't work in IE usually, because it doesn't come installed on a PC by default. That's what fallbacks are for.

Here's some information about what is typically available for whom.

http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/sampler-CombinedResults.shtml